# JavaFX - bug in cell render after hiding columns

Tags: javafx, tableview, uitableview

First of all sorry for my English:)
I have a strange bug... I'd like to hide some columns in JavaFX TableView after pressing the button. The code is as simple as possible:

```
                column8.visibleProperty().set(false);
                column9.visibleProperty().set(false);
```

(I also tested with remove with the same result).
The problem is that in "neighboring cell" I have "separator" from somewhere after this action. 
I use Cellfactories is my code. For one of the hidden Cell it is

```
column8.setCellFactory(column -> {
    return new TableCell<Anfrage, Mandant>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Mandant item, boolean empty) {                    
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {  
                setText(item.getNameMandant());                       
            }
        }                                
    };                       
});
```

And for cell, where I have "separator" after hiding:

```
//Store
column10.setCellFactory(column -> {
    return new TableCell<Anfrage, Terminals>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Terminals item, boolean empty) {                    
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {  
                setText(item.getStore());                     
            }
        }                                
    };                       
});
```

Some pics to explain what is actually wrong.
[image: Before hiding]
[image: After hiding]

If i set visible to "true" again everythings works as expected - all columns are in there without any "separators" anywhere.

Thanks a lot for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally tableview refreshing is resolved in JavaFX 8u60. Now "native" `table.refresh()` do the trick.